# Totals of cells values in html table whith jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this structure of html table :

```
<table class="global_table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="mytable">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan=2></th>
                    <th>A</th>
                    <th>B</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td class="value"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="value"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="mytable">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan=2></th>
                    <th>A</th>
                    <th>B</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td class="value"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td class="value"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="value"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="mytable">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan=2></th>
                    <th>A</th>
                    <th>B</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td class="value"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="value"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="value"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="mytable">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan=2></th>
                    <th>A</th>
                    <th>B</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="value"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="mytotal">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan=2></th>
                    <th>A</th>
                    <th>B</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>T</td>
                    <td>=</td>
                    <td class="tot"></td>
                    <td class="tot"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[global_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFNAM.jpg)

i want when i click in red cells, the value of coeficient showed in the target cell. But each sub table must have one value, like this :

[Result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOOpE.jpg)

Finally i want to calculate the total of each column in the blue cells

Thank you

Comment: Do it the other way round. Thats easier. Create an array: rows=[]; add columns: column=[]; rows.push(columns); than generate the html

Comment: or, use same classes for A columns that you want to calculate, and same with B columns, later select the right columns with jQuery (A or B), and calculate the results whenever needed

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answers. Can you explain me with an example please ?